# problems detecting 'Inline String' cell values using SAX parsing in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, saxparser

I have a huge excel file which I am trying to parse using SAX parser in JAVA. I am mostly making use of Apache POI library and working with .XLSX files. Here is how xml contents looks inside zipped excel folder at `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` which i am trying to read:

```
<row r="1">
<c r="A1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>my value 1</t></is></c>
<c r="B1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>my value 2</t></is></c>
<c r="C1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>my value 3</t></is></c>
</row>
```

This one particular excel file is making use of inline string values as shown above.

This my function which executes the program to read the file:

```
public void executeExcelDataExtraction() throws IOException, OpenXML4JException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError {
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(XLSX_INPUT_FILE.xlsx);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
    ImportArticleDataProcessorExcelFileReaderFactory handlerFactory = new 
         ImportArticleDataProcessorExcelFileReaderFactory(sst);
    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(handlerFactory);
    Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
    if (sheets instanceof XSSFReader.SheetIterator) {
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator sheetiterator = 
             (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)sheets;
        while(sheetiterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
            InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
            rowCache = handlerFactory.getRowCache();
            sheet.close();
            pkg.close();
            if(!rowCache.isEmpty()) 
                createCategoryMap(rowCache);                
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my sheet handler factory class which is used in above function.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ImportArticleDataProcessorExcelFileReaderFactory extends DefaultHandler{

    private static final String ROW_EVENT = "row";
    private static final String CELL_EVENT = "c";
    private SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;
    private List<String> cellCache = new LinkedList<>();
    private List<String[]> rowCache = new LinkedList<>();

    ImportArticleDataProcessorExcelFileReaderFactory(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        this.sst = sst;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if (CELL_EVENT.equals(name)) {
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        } else if (ROW_EVENT.equals(name)) {
            if (!cellCache.isEmpty()) {
                rowCache.add(cellCache.toArray(new String[cellCache.size()]));
            }
            cellCache.clear();
        }
        lastContents = "";
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        // Process the last contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        if(nextIsString) {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
            lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;
        }

        // v => contents of a cell
        // Output after we've seen the string contents
        if(name.equals("v")) {
            cellCache.add(lastContents.trim());
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public List<String[]> getRowCache() {
        return rowCache;
    }

}
```

All other excel files which are not having inline string are able to read successfully, however with files having inline string inside, the algorithm only reads `cellType=inlineStr` but never gets the right value.

**What I want:**

All I want is just to print the values located inside inline string cell e.g. in my case it is "my value 1", "my value 2" and "my value 3"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843618/how-to-check-a-number-in-a-string-contains-a-date-and-exponential-numbers-while/48889186#48889186

Comment: @AxelRichter wow! this answer solved my problem. I did few changes as shown in that answer. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking for similar solution, just want to let you know that i have solved it by adding these few lines in my `ImportArticleDataProcessorExcelFileReaderFactory` class above:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name){

        // rest of the code...

        inlineStr = false;
        if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("inlineStr")) {
            inlineStr = true;
        } 
        ...
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name){

        // rest of the code...

       if(name.equals("t") && inlineStr) {
          cellCache.add(lastContents.trim());
       }
       ...
}
```

`void characters` function in above factory class correctly identifies contents of the cell and my changes as given in my answer successfully fills `cellCache` list with all the values from inline string cells.

please refer to @Axel's answer in comment above and follow this answer for your source: [How to check a number in a string contains a date and exponential numbers while parsing excel file using apache event model in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843618/how-to-check-a-number-in-a-string-contains-a-date-and-exponential-numbers-while/48889186#48889186)